# PHP Weird Undefined index error

Tags: php, arrays, http-headers

I have a really frustrating issue where I cannot retrieve any of the headers. Here is my code:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
echo($headers["SystemTime"]); //Doesnt work
$keys = array_keys($headers);
echo($headers[$keys[4]]); //Doesnt work
```

Both lines produce the error 'Undefined index: SystemTime'.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I cant get the value. If I go `print_r($headers);` I get this

```
Array
(
    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [Content-Length] => 0
    [Host] => localhost
    [Referer] => 
    [SystemTime] => 2012-06-26+09%3a20%3a27
)
```

var_dump of $headers

```
array(5) {
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ["Content-Length"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Host"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["Referer"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SystemTime"]=>
  string(23) "2012-06-26+10%3a10%3a08"
}
```

var_dump of $keys

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Content-Type"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "Content-Length"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Host"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "Referer"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "SystemTime"
}

foreach ($headers as $name => $value) { 
   echo "$name: $value. From Array: {$headers[$name]}\n"; 
}
```

returned:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive. From Array: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. From Array: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 0. From Array: 0
Host: localhost. From Array: localhost
Referer: . From Array: 

Notice:  Undefined index:  SystemTime in /clientdata/apache-www/a/d/[XXXXXX].com/www/admin/request/GetPCLicence.php on line 22
SystemTime: 2012-06-26+10%3a10%3a08. From Array:
```

Im stuck and I seriously cannot figure out what is going wrong. It should work.

PS. I know that the SystemTime header is non-standard. I provide that from my http_request.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to see if the strings (keys) are what you expect (e.g. null bytes or unicode ws). Also `SystemTime` isn't a standard header. Who added it? And by "any of the headers" do you mean you tried the ordinary ones?

Comment: My client end is in C#. I know 100% that it works. The code I posted above is actually the first few lines of my code.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what `$headers = getallheaders(); foreach ($headers as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value.  From Array: {$headers[$name]}\n";
}
` results in.

Comment: Your foreach results are posted above

Comment: Looks like YAPHPB, I'd recommend posting in their support forum. When index is deliverable via foreach, but is not really registered as array index, it's something went wrong big time.

Comment: AHA! I tried it on my paid web-server (verses my localhost) and it worked..

Comment: On the other thought, it's 5.2.17... Is it supported right now?

Comment: Let me guess: your web-server PHP version is not 5.2? )

Comment: @CraigWhite Thanks for that.  Obviously showed that something is not quite right.  I checked PHP 5.2 source but saw nothing special about SystemTime so that's odd.  Is it easy to change your C# app to use something like `SystemTime_` or `SysTime` to see if there are other/similar words that don't work right?

Comment: PHP doesn't like any other headers I send it, other than standard things like useragent and stuff.

Comment: What about json_decode(json_encode($headers)) ?

Comment: That code produced: `Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: What about unserialize(serialize($headers)) ?

Comment: Serializing produced: `array(5) {
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ["Content-Length"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Host"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["Referer"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SystemTime"]=>
  string(23) "2012-06-26+10%3a43%3a10"
}
`

Comment: Could you access "Systemtime" index after unserialize/seialize procedure?

Comment: YES I COULD! Accessing of the data worked after serializing and deserializing! But why???

Comment: Because f*ck the PHP, thats why! I really dont understand this! The answer may be finded inside getallheaders() function I think

Comment: I GOT IT! Answer going below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it after much help from you guys. I had a feeling that because it worked after the deserializing that maybe the encoding was different and thats why we could see it, but not touch it?

My code below gets all the headers and converts the encoding and puts it in a new array :)

Here is my 'Translation' code.

```
    $headersRaw = getallheaders();
    $headers = array();
    foreach($headersRaw as $key => $value)
    {
        $headers[mb_convert_encoding($key, "UTF-8")] = $value;
    }
```

Comment: You are a PHP Chuck Norris I think!

Comment: *Round ElePHPant Kick* Kapow!

Comment: Sounds plausible, but that doesn't explain that `foreach` snippet behavior: we used something that was supplied by `foreach`, but that didn't count as a key.

Comment: I'd rather suppose here we have the same mechanisms working as with unserialize/serialize.

Comment: Its possible that when using [index] it changes the encoding and thats why we couldn't access via the same value we just retrieved via the foreach.

Comment: Can I name my daughter Craig?

Comment: Worked for me without `mb_convert_encoding` as well with `$headers[$key] = $value;`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet at this point may be to use the `$_SERVER` superglobal get the values of any headers you need (e.g. `$_SERVER['HTTP_SYSTEMTIME']`.

I couldn't reproduce the problem on my system (PHP 5.4.3) by calling `getallheaders()` and sending a custom request just like yours with the `SystemTime`header set to `2012-06-26+10%3a10%3a08`.  It worked as expected and I see the value printed out twice (once having used `getallheaders()` and once using `$_SERVER`.  This could very well be a strange PHP bug as I don't see any special notes about the function `apache_request_headers`, or anything strange about its code in the 5.2.17 branch of PHP.

Hope this helps for the time being.  Using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_*']` may be more reliable anyway as the `getallheaders` isn't available in all configurations.

Comment: I had already tried this. I obtained a function from http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php at the bottom of the page which produced the same results, which does what you specify. (I removed the function checking and made it `getAllHeadersEx()`)

Comment: Ok so the `$_SERVER['HTTP_SYSTEMTIME']` is also not populated?

Comment: Its there but not accessible.